# How to get total documents in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

```
usermodel.find({ 'word': { $regex: `.*${word2}.*` } })
        .populate('user').limit(3)
        .skip(page).exec((err, searches) => {
```

})

How do I get the number of documents (total) when using the limit and skip?
It gives me total when I use mongoose-paginate
but how can i get total here ?

Comment: You can't, you have to split it into 2 calls, one the paginate query and one to count the total. this is basically what `mongoose-paginate` does.

Comment: @tomslabbaert No problem if the number of requests is high?

Comment: @tomslabbaert how about `$facet`?

Comment: very inefficient

Comment: @tomslabbaert please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run two separate queries using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/):

```
usermodel.aggregate([
    { $match: { your query goes here } },
    {
        $facet: {
            filtered: [ { $limit: 3 } ],
            total: [ { $count: "total" } ]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$total"
    }
])
```

Comment: I want to have the total docs found . this code give total documents in usermodel collection . do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Julia see my modified answer